# How does Google Drive bi-directional synchronization work?

Tags: google-drive, synchronization

I have my Google Drive synchronized with my computer folder (Google Drive) on windows PC.

What happens if I delete one file in my online Google Drive interface in browser?

What happens if I delete one file in my offline computer folder?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just try it yourself? All you had to do was make a couple of junk files and see what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if I delete one file in my online Google Drive interface in browser?

The file will be moved to your Google Drive "[Trash](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/trash)" folder and will be removed from your hard drive<sup>1</sup>.

> What happens if I delete one file in my offline computer folder?

The file will be removed from your hard drive<sup>1</sup> and will be moved to the "[Trash](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/trash)" folder within Google Drive.

It works the same for Google Drive native files (Docs, Sheets, Slides) as well as other files. I confirmed this by creating four files: two Google Docs and two text files. I then deleted one of each from the Web, then one of each from my hard drive, and observed the results.

---

<sup>1</sup> In both cases, it appears that the file will also be recoverable from your OS "Recycle Bin". This may vary for you depending on your local settings.